# Как локально прочитать в терминале Rails документацию в ri tools / rdoc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems

При установке Rails устанавливается документация(локально) но не могу найти ответов как её прочитать в терминале.
LinuxMint 18.3 Rails 5.1.4

Comment: http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#viewing-documentation

Answer (score 2):

Для доступа к документации в командной строке вызвать **ri**, например:

`ri ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements`

Если нет документации по какому-то гему, то  возможно, что он был установлен без неё. Для того, чтобы сгенерировать документацию для всех гемов в командной строке вызовите:

`gem rdoc --all --ri --no-rdoc`

Чтобы установить доку для конкретного гема, вместо опции `--all` ввести название гема, например:

`gem rdoc pg --ri --no-rdoc`